# Buttons too small for content

Tags: front-end, grid-layouts, button, size, text-formatting

When I try to display buttons with long content in a multicolumn the text sometimes gets cut off. Like this:

```
fileNames = \
{"QC_eta0-7100_Nx35_Ny35_e2-5000_g1-1500_alpha0-4142_X0-7000_\
Niterations50000000", 
   "QC_eta0-7150_Nx35_Ny35_e2-5000_g1-1500_alpha0-4142_X0-7000_\
Niterations50000000", 
   "QC_eta0-7200_Nx35_Ny35_e2-5000_g1-1500_alpha0-4142_X0-7000_\
Niterations50000000", 
   "QC_eta0-7250_Nx35_Ny35_e2-5000_g1-1500_alpha0-4142_X0-7000_\
Niterations50000000"};
buttons = ((Button[ToString[#], currentFolder = #] &) /@ fileNames);
Multicolumn[buttons, 4] // TableForm
```

[image]

I found the (quite simple solution) so I will share this for later reference.

Comment: `fileNames = 
 StringTemplate[
   "QC_eta0-\`\`_Nx35_Ny35_e2-5000_g1-1500_alpha0-4142_X0-7000_\
Niterations50000000"] /@ Range[7100, 7250, 50]`

Comment: @BobHanlon In my actual notebook I read those string from a folder so this doesn't really help me here. I included the minimal code that would reproduce the problem, so `fileNames` could be any collection of long strings. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `ImageSize -> Automatic` to the buttons makes them get larger based on their content. By default this is set to `ImageSize -> Full` which will make them as large as possible considering their environment but disregards content.

```
fileNames = \
{"QC_eta0-7100_Nx35_Ny35_e2-5000_g1-1500_alpha0-4142_X0-7000_\
Niterations50000000", 
   "QC_eta0-7150_Nx35_Ny35_e2-5000_g1-1500_alpha0-4142_X0-7000_\
Niterations50000000", 
   "QC_eta0-7200_Nx35_Ny35_e2-5000_g1-1500_alpha0-4142_X0-7000_\
Niterations50000000", 
   "QC_eta0-7250_Nx35_Ny35_e2-5000_g1-1500_alpha0-4142_X0-7000_\
Niterations50000000"};
buttons = ((Button[ToString[#], currentFolder = #, 
       ImageSize -> Automatic] &) /@ fileNames);
Multicolumn[buttons, 4] // TableForm
```

[image]